# Creating "space" for each new column value, while using Col. 1 value as reference

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file like this:

```
-2  abandonar
-2  abandono
-2  abandonas
-2  abandona
-2  abandonamos
-2  abandonáis
-2  abandonan   
-4  abandonado
-4  abandonada
-4  abandonados
-4  abandonadas 
-5  abandona    
-5  abandonos                                       
-3  secuestrado 
-3  secuestrada 
-3  secuestrados    
-3  secuestradas    
-3  secuestraría    
-3  secuestrarías   
-3  secuestraríamos
-3  secuestraríais
-3  secuestrarían
```

I want the output to retain col 1  and all other columns added just in a line as shown in the desired output 
Desired output:

```
-2  abandonar   abandono    abandonas   abandona    abandonamos abandonáis  abandonan   
-4  abandonado  abandonada  abandonados abandonadas 
-5  abandona    abandonos                                       
-3  secuestrado secuestrada secuestrados    secuestradas    secuestraría    secuestrarías   secuestraríamos secuestraríais  secuestrarían
```

My effort so far:

```
nawk '1' RS='\n' ORS=' ' filename
```

and

```
awk '{RS="\n"; ORS=" "}{ print }' filename
```

Please I need your support preferably using awk, I a newbie. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '$1!=p{printf "%s%s", (NR>1?ORS:""), $1; p=$1} {printf "%s%s", OFS, $2} END{print ""}' file
-2 abandonar abandono abandonas abandona abandonamos abandonáis abandonan
-4 abandonado abandonada abandonados abandonadas
-5 abandona abandonos
-3 secuestrado secuestrada secuestrados secuestradas secuestraría secuestrarías secuestraríamos secuestraríais secuestrarían
```

To learn Awk, read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins?

Comment: Thanks a lot Ed, it worked perfectly and also thanks for the book. You are the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=a[$1] " " $2} END {for (i in a) { print i, a[i] }}' file
-4  abandonado abandonada abandonados abandonadas
-3  secuestrado secuestrada secuestrados secuestradas secuestraría secuestrarías secuestraríamos secuestraríais secuestrarían
-2  abandonar abandono abandonas abandona abandonamos abandonáis abandonan
-5  abandona abandonos
```

Comment: Thanks for your support.